# Know if last file in a folder is older than 1 hour

Tags: linux, bash, time

I've tried this:

```
if find filename -mmin +60; then echo banana; fi
```

but it doesn't seem to work: it echoes banana in any case.

How can I echo banana only if the file is older than 60 minutes?

Comment: This isn't going to work; `find` only gives a non-zero exit code if a processing **error** occurred;  the run is still successful, even your condition isn't met.  You need to count the output lines of find for that file, and if it's `1` your condition is met.

Comment: What is `filename` - the name of _a folder_, or the name of the _last file_ (whatever that means)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use both `stat` and `date`:

```
((($(date +%s) - $(stat -c +%X file)) < 3600)) && echo banana
```

`date +%s` gives the current time in epoch format.

`stat -c +%X` give the last access time of the file `filename` in the same format. Use other options like `%W`, `%Y` for respectively the birth and modification time.

Answer (score 0):

Turning the comment above into something answerish: `find` only gives a non-zero exit code if a processing **error** occurred; the run is still successful, even if your condition isn't met. You need to count the output lines of find for that file, and if it's 1 your condition is met (if there's only one file by that name in the directory you're scanning; otherwise change `-eq` to `-ge`).

```
if [[ $( find filename -mmin +60 | wc -l ) -eq 1 ]]; then echo banana; fi 
banana
```

Comment: This is a an anti-pattern.  Much better to write `if find filename -mmin +60 | grep -q .; then ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
find filename -mmin +60 -printf 'banana\n' -quit
```

Comment: Mmm... I am expecting a bumper crop of bananas if there are multiple files over an hour old.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thanks for reporting the bug.  I assumed that `filename` was an ordinary file, not a directory.  I've updated the code to try to fix the problem.